# Set environment variables to be used outside of npm within npm script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Is there a way of setting environment variable such that it could be used outside of `npm` (more specifically on linux).
For eg: Let's say I wanted to extract the package version of something and use it in a totally separate, non node CI file?
I've tried setting the variable using `env`, `cross-env`, `export` but they're only available within `npm`.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood it correctly, you'd like to set environment variable? If so, just search for "setting environment variables on linux" :)

1. https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/administration-linux/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-linux/
2. https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-set-and-list-environment-variables-in-linux/
3. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-read-and-set-environmental-and-shell-variables-on-a-linux-vps